# Connect to OPC DA server from LabVIEW

Tags: labview, opc, opc-da

I have to connect to OPC DA server from LabVIEW and read more than 400 tags synchronously/asynchronously. I know there is an option with NI DSC module to create LabVIEW OPC client.
The problem is I do not want to buy NI DSC license because it has overhead functionality and hence costs a lot.

I am curios if you had an experience to connect OPC DA server without NI DSC from LabVIEW.

Comment: It seems I found some toolkit: http://opc-da.com/ . What do you think about this one? Has someone tried to use?

Comment: People have done this with the QuickOPC toolkit (http://www.opclabs.com). Disclaimer: This is a self-promotion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Yair's answer I have found an very useful toolkit [here](http://opc-da.com/) for $295 that provides fast and simple mechanism to connect to OPC servers from LabVIEW. I have tested with trial mode and it seems my problems are solved with this. 
http://opc-da.com/

Answer (score 1):

The DataSocket Read primitive supports OPC, but my understanding was that it doesn't really work well with a large number of tags. My own experience with it was with a relatively low number of tags and years ago, so you will have to test for yourself, but it should be built into LV, so it satisfies the cost requirement. You could possibly also control the way you read the tags to work around any performance issues it might have.

Note that you will probably need to add DS support to any installer you build.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have successfully were able to connect to OPC DA server, but it works really-really slow and will not support even 50 tags :).

Comment: It seems I found some toolkit: http://opc-da.com/ . What do you think about this one?

Comment: I think that you can use it in trial mode, so I suggest you do that. You could also try looking for external OPC utilities (using a C or .NET API), but my guess is that finding a free one might be difficult.

Comment: I have tried the example and VIs. They worked just perfect for me. Much much faster. I were able to read all the data. Unfortunately the evaluation period is 10 days only. So I have to buy. I think the right answer for my question is using OPC-DA toolkit for LabVIEW. Would you mind to change your answer, so I can accept it? Or you/or me should post another answer?

Comment: My answer was about using DS. Since your solution is about another tool, I would suggest you post it as a separate answer.